# How to know an ag-grid menu was closed?

Tags: contextmenu, ag-grid-react

I'm using AGgrid react, and I need to know when an ag menu was closed. Basically, right-clicking a cell opens a menu (Context menu), and clicking elsewhere closes/hides the menu. So would like to listen to that onClose event somehow.
Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

$('.ag-root').hasClass('ag-context-menu-open')